# Error en conexión java mySQL

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

He probado varias formas de conectar java a mySQL pero ninguno funciona y quiero saber si el fallo esta en el código o en algún otro factor del pc, porque es la primera vez que trabajo desde este equipo.

```
package practicabd;

import java.sql.*;

public class PracticaBD {



public static void main(String[] args) {
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/colegio";
    String username = "java";
    String password = "password";

    System.out.println("Connecting database...");

    try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password)) {
        System.out.println("Database connected!");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Cannot connect the database!", e);
    }
}

}
```

El query de mySQL es este:

```
create database colegio;
use colegio;

CREATE TABLE ALUMNOS(
CODIGO int NOT NULL,
NOMBRE varchar(100) NOT NULL,
APELLIDOS varchar(100) NOT NULL,
EDAD int NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(CODIGO)
);

CREATE USER 'java'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL ON colegio.* TO 'java'@'localhost';
```

La consola devuelve lo siguiente:

> Connecting database...
>   Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot connect the database!
>       at practicabd.PracticaBD.main(PracticaBD.java:29)
>   Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: The server time zone value 'Hora est�ndar romance' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the 'serverTimezone' configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89)
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63)
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:73)
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:76)
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836)
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.(ConnectionImpl.java:456)
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246)
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:197)
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
>       at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
>       at practicabd.PracticaBD.main(PracticaBD.java:26)
>   Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.InvalidConnectionAttributeException: The server time zone value 'Hora est�ndar romance' is unrecognized or represents more than one time zone. You must configure either the server or JDBC driver (via the 'serverTimezone' configuration property) to use a more specifc time zone value if you want to utilize time zone support.
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>       at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61)
>       at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:85)
>       at com.mysql.cj.util.TimeUtil.getCanonicalTimezone(TimeUtil.java:132)
>       at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.configureTimezone(NativeProtocol.java:2118)
>       at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeProtocol.initServerSession(NativeProtocol.java:2142)
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.initializePropsFromServer(ConnectionImpl.java:1310)
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:967)
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:826)
>       ... 6 more
>   C:\Users\Alfonso\AppData\Local\NetBeans\Cache\8.2\executor-snippets\run.xml:53: Java returned: 1
>   BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)

Comment: Podrias verificar si tienes el JDBC Driver bien configurado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes poner en la url de la BD algo como:

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/colegio?serverTimezone=UTC";
```

El problema es que el TimeZone de la BD no es igual al TimeZone de la aplicación.

También podrías poner el timezone para la BD, utilizando algo como:

`SET GLOBAL time_zone ='+00:00'` o `'+3:00'` dependiendo de tu zona horaria.

Comment: Ya se me conecta perfectamente. Muchisimas gracias